# Plot labels disappearing

Tags: graphics

Using Mathematica 11.2 (Win 10), when the notebook containing the chart below is reopened the plot labels have disappeared.  What's happening?

```
dates = {{2003, 12, 31}, {2004, 1, 31}, {2004, 2, 29}, {2004, 3, 31},
   {2004, 4, 30}, {2004, 5, 31}, {2004, 6, 30}, {2004, 7, 31}, {2004, 8, 31},
   {2004, 9, 30}, {2004, 10, 31}};

a = {100, 99.3845, 97.6528, 98.7795, 101.262, 97.3712, 98.2474, 97.6424,
   98.5395, 98.3831, 97.538};
b = {100, 101.061, 101.241, 101.416, 100.315, 99.7269, 99.5349, 99.189,
   99.0258, 99.4548, 99.8426};

DateListPlot[Transpose[{dates, #}] & /@ {a, b}, BaseStyle -> 12,
 PlotLegends -> {"Series A", "Series B"}, PlotLabel -> "Example"]
```

[image]

This is how the chart looks when the notebook is reopened.

[image]

Comment: I am getting the same.

Comment: Same on OS X. When I opened the notebook in 11.2 it was fine but 12.0 no ticks